# It is possible to upload a file with ajax and percent feedback to an iis 6 server with plain asp support?

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

Shame on me, but i have a plain asp iis6 server and they want an ajax upload input with percent upload feedback, what should i do? do i ask for .net capabilities? any guidelines or some advice? Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need a flash/silverlight component to do this, like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).  I think there's also a way to do it [without Flash using an iFrame hack or something](http://www.aspupload.com/manual_progress.html), but I've never gotten that to work right.